# Common Type of List<string>

Tags: c#, string, list, tryparse

I have a list of strings and want to find out if they share any of the predefined C# types other than string, additionaly I want to check for dates.

Is there an existing way to do this other than a cascade of TryParse's?

**UPDATE**

The source of these strings is an excel csv file for example

**Id; Company; Average Salary; Founding Date**
123; Microsoft; 2350.78; 01.02.1911
65; Apple; 2100.50; 16.07.1934

With obvious types for people not for a computer, but if you add this additional line the most specific type of column "Id" would be string.

4A; IBM; 2800.0; 01.01.1923

The Idea could be something like Type inference
[Haskell Type inference](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Type_inference)

Comment: A little bit code would be more helpful...

Comment: You can probably use regular expressions and for dates: DateTime.TryParse

Comment: What is the question, why you expect other types to figure out in a `List<string>` ?

Comment: The class `string` is a `sealed` type. Therefore all the (non-null) items in a `List<string>` will be of the same runtime type, namely `string`. Some instances, like `"20130621"` might be interpreted as (converted or parsed into) many different "standard" types, in this case for example `DateTime`, `int`, `long`, `double`, `decimal`, and others.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Regex to find if a string can be converted to a type, here are some regex examples http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html

Answer (score 0):

Since the input is CSV file the data types should be known in advance.
i.e. you already know that ID is a string, Company is a string, Avg Salary is a double, Founding date is a date, etc..

You should code around a spec and gracefully handle user errors when data is malformed.

I have a class that might help though:

```
/// <summary>
        /// Translate a text value to its setting type
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="type">Type to convert to</param>
        /// <param name="value">string to cast</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static object CastHelper(Type type, string value)
        {
            switch (type.Name)
            {
                case "Int32":
                    return Convert.ToInt32(value);

                case "Byte":
                    return Convert.ToByte(value);

                case "Boolean":
                    return Convert.ToBoolean(value);

                case "Color":
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            string[] rgb = value.Split(',');
                            return Color.FromArgb(Convert.ToInt32(rgb[0]), Convert.ToInt32(rgb[1]), Convert.ToInt32(rgb[2]));
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            return Color.FromName(value);
                        }

                    }
                case "Font":
                    return (new FontConverter().ConvertFromString(value));

                default:
                    return value;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Obviously you would have to modify CastHelper to the types you want to work with.